# Is there a way to use the request query parameter value in the response

Tags: postman, postman-mocks

I am trying to create a Mock API server using Postman. My request will have a query parameter `key`. I want to use the value passed to the `key` query parameter in the mock response.

**Request**: `{{url}}/foo?key=3`

**Response**:

```json
{
   "3": {
      ...
   }
}
```

---

I tried `{{url}}/foo?key={{key}}`

```json
{
    "{{key}}": {
        ...
    }
}
```

but that's just returning the `{{key}}` text as it is without any replacements. Is there any way I can use the query parameter values in the mock response?

Comment: I'm facing the same question. Did you find a solution for this? Thanks in advance.